# CSRF server token in POST response or in HTTP header (instead of cookie)

Tags: ajax, cookies, csrf

I have two sites: first with login page on site http://SITE and second with main application module on site http://SITE/WEB.
The login process goes like this:

1. On SITE user types his login.
2. SITE sends login to SITE/WEB (via POST AJAX).
3. SITE/WEB responses with some password chars.
4. Still on SITE user types password chars.
5. SITE sends password to SITE/WEB (via POST AJAX).
6. SITE/WEB responses "OK" when password is correct.
7. If "OK" SITE redirects (in JS) to SITE/WEB.

Now, I want to add CSRF attack protection - **also on login page**. 
Protection SITE/WEB with sending CSRF token in cookie is not problem at all but on logon page **I can't use cookie created on SITE/WEB because cookie will have "Path=/WEB"** so on SITE I can't read it.

So should I do in this situation?
I'm thinking about sending a token in header or simply in POST response in step 3 - together with password chars.
Will it be secure?

Comment: The path the cookie is valid for is the one _you specify_ ... so that argument seems rather bogus already. And whether you send plain text data via a cookie, an additional request header or simply as part of the request body of course makes no difference at all in regard to it “being secure”. HTTPS is what takes care of not letting that info leak to the outside.

Comment: @CBroe OK, I didn't mention that I use Play Framework as server on SITE/WEB and the context /WEB is defined there. In short: PF adds internally context to cookie path so I can't change it.

Comment: @CBroe One more: if setting CSRF token in header or in POST response instead of set-cookie has no difference so setting cookie is only for... convenience, habit? And what if it would be no HTTPS? I suppose with set-cookie CSRF token I'm secured. And if I send token via header/POST?

Comment: It does not matter whether you send the value via header, cookie or as a POST parameter - without HTTPS, _all_ of that data is readable by an attacker in the middle. You want HTTPS, without that it does not even make sense to start further thinking about “security” ...